# How to effectively fetch organization hierarchy from Microsoft Graph API using Pyspark/Python?

Tags: python, azure, pyspark, microsoft-graph-api, azure-databricks

I'm trying to get the organization hierarchy (top to bottom approach) using Microsoft Graph API in Azure Databricks.

Below is the API I'm trying to query - 
`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id}/directReports`

Code Used -

```
url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id}/directReports"

payload={}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

df = spark.read.json(sc.parallelize([response.text]))

df = df.select(f.explode_outer('value').alias('data'))

df = df.select("data.*")
df.write.mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("default.orgTree")
```

Now, for the 1st instance (topmost level is CEO) it works. Below are the list of columns I was able to populate within `default.orgTree`-

```
['@odata.type',  'businessPhones',  'displayName',  'givenName',  'id',  'jobTitle',  'mail',  'mobilePhone',  'officeLocation',  'preferredLanguage',  'surname',  'userPrincipalName']
```

However, next level(I fetched all the `id` - extracted under 1st iteration) onwards in some cases there are blanks and in some cases it contains multiple string dictionaries within a list. My requirement is to iterate till the lowest level (till whichever level direct reportee is available ) and append in `default.orgTree` respectively for parent and child.

Is there an effective way to achieve this complex scenario? I'm bit confused how to handle the subsequent iterations.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the below endpoints exist today for Org Hierarchy.

Up

```
GET /me/manager
GET /users/{id | userPrincipalName}/manager
```

Down

```
GET /me/directReports
GET /users/{id | userPrincipalName}/directReports
```

Being said this, for you specific scenario consider filing [user voice](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/idb-p/Microsoft365DeveloperPlatform) so that it could be considered for future implementations.

Comment: Have already tried this. However, is there a way to convert it into structured format for subsequent iterations ? Having said that, I would like to know, the employees working under each of the managers and insert this into the existing table. One constraint, I noticed was that under each iteration, it can pull details for no more than 100 employees. I presume, I need to take care of that using refresh token. But that's a separate discussion altogether.